# How can I improve my downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am trying to get my question into a positive vote state. How can I improve my question for upvotes?

Here is the question:
*[How do I pass arguments to a command inside a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436635/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-a-command-inside-a-powershell-script)*

Comment: I would suggest reading [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) by Jon Skeet. The tips there are very helpful. Also, make sure you've read the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, as well. These two should give you a good idea of improving your question **as well as** learning how to ask increasingly better ones in the future.

Answer (score 11):

All I can really do is grumble at this, since...well, you're in a Catch-22.

The question you're asking isn't necessarily a bad one.  You want to know how to use command line arguments from your shell of choice and pass those into your Java app.  What makes me grumble is a lack of effort shown; that is, you don't list what you did or how it went.  However, in defense of asking questions period, sometimes you just don't *know* how to do a thing and you're looking for insight.

So in all reality, if you can't show what you initially tried, there's no way to really improve the question to make it more palatable for future readers, which means you're stuck, hence the grumbling.  You want to improve but there's little to no wiggle room for improvement on this one.

Comment: The OP could at least add "I searched on google for 'accessing powershell command line arguments in script' and 'foo' etc" which would be enough for me at least to know that they've put some effort into researching it themselves